# Issue With Azure Blob Access From Python Function

Tags: python, azure, blob

I created an Azure Function in Python to play with accessing Azure Blobs.  I created an Azure storage account and then saved a small text file in a blob container as shown below.

[image: Azure Storage Explorer screenshot]

My Azure Function is:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, myblob: func.InputStream) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    blobname = myblob.name
    bloblength = myblob.length
    bloburi = myblob.uri
    strFileContents = myblob.read()


    return func.HttpResponse(f"Name {blobname}, Blob size {bloblength}")
```

When I locally debug and hit the function from a browser, it is getting values of None for the blob length, name, and uri.  However, I can successfully read the contents of the file.  This is shown in the debugger screenshot below.

Can someone help me understand why I can read the contents of the file but can't get the length, name, and uri?  Thanks.

[VS Code Azure Function Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX0fb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata of the [blob input binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=csharp) (e.g. name, length) is not provided by the function host at this point of time.

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/576

The suggestion would be to make us of the Azure Storage SDK.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.